# Visual Studio 2015 Community Freezes when Subsystem is "Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)"

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have been trying to diagnose this problem for hours now. I did repaired Visual Studio through Control Panel and also used an installation CD to try and repair. Basically whenever I have an application even as simple as Hello World like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

The project will build and when it gets to the third line in debugging that looks something like:

1> HelloTest.vcxproj - > C:\Users\Username\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Debug\HelloTest.exe

The whole program will freeze and the only way to do anything else is to manually exit the program through Task Manager. I have no idea what I did. Earlier during another project I was having linker problems and when I reset Subsystem equal to "Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)" is when I started getting problems.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: You'll need to get your machine healthy again.  That usually start with disabling the kind of software that always gets its underwear in a bundle when it sees an executable file appear from no-where.   Disable your anti-malware, get rid of it completely if it is Avast or ESET.

Comment: I do have Avast installed. Unfortunately I got so fed up earlier I uninstalled Visual Studio. I am going to reinstall VS and remove Avast and then post an update. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: So your solution to remove my antivirus software, specifically Avast seemed to work after I reinstalled Visual Studio. I wonder why I had not initially run into problems but I am very happy that it is working smoothly now. Have a wonderful day!