# "Hello world!" freeze in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I tried to compile a simple Hello World in C++ to test that my Visual Studio 2013 on my Windows 10 works well but I've a problem. My program compile but when I run, it freeze. It's an empty Win32 Console Application with a "main.cpp" :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!";
    return 0;
}
```

- If I launch it from Visual Studio in debug (with "Run"), Visual Studio freeze and I need to kill its task.
- If I launch it with the executable or with "Run without Debugging", nothing appear, "System" process doesn't want to free the execution and I can't recompile without restart the computer because of that.

I am confused. If somebody have an idea of what's happening, please help me.

**Update 1** : I repair my installation. Same problem. Breakpoint doesn't help. It seems to freeze before. And also no trace of a task in the task manager when launched without debugging.

Comment: It might be a problem with your local machine/os/vs installation. Without more information, it's pretty much impossible to diagnose it.

Comment: Windows 10 & Visual Studio 2013 without optional installs.

Comment: try running your programme with "step over" or F10 and see if you can step through your main routine

Comment: If you run it from VS the DOS box will disappear right away; set a breakpoint at the closing curly brace of main(), or better, open a DOS box and run the program by typing its path. Then you see any problems that may happen. Also, add a newline to make sure the output buffer is flushed before the program exits, possibly not cleanly.

Comment: Also, could you really not kill the process from the task manager (because you need to restart the *computer*)? That is unusual.

Comment: I just repair my installation. Same problem. Breakpoint doesn't help. It seems to freeze before. And no trace of a task in the task manager.

Comment: We had another user recently reporting similar problems of MSVC freezing up on him for trivial programs...?!?

Comment: Very peculiar - try changing the build options (particularly the platform target) and trying again. It might be something to do with the type of application it is being built for. Then try a download of VS2015 (community edition is full-featured and free) to see if the problem remains.

Comment: @DevSolar: [I think this might be the other related question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666895/visual-studio-2015-community-freezes-when-subsystem-is-console-subsystemcons) The issue appeared to be due to Avast antivirus.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: You got it. It was Avast. I disable it and it works. Thanks all !

Comment: @ReMinoer: You might try excluding your "\Visual Studio 2013\Projects" folder in Avast instead of completely disabling your antivirus.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Yes, clearly better. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was my antivirus' fault (in my case, Avast). I made it ignore my Visual Studio projects and it works. Solved by @Blastfurnace.